# How to compile ELSD on Ubuntu? link errors

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, linker

I'm trying to compile this on Ubuntu but it doesn't link and I don't understand why.

http://ubee.enseeiht.fr/vision/ELSD/

```
home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$ make
cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -o elsd elsd.c valid_curve.c process_curve.c process_line.c write_svg.c -llapack_LINUX -lblas_LINUX -llibf2c -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack_LINUX
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas_LINUX
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibf2c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [elsd] Error 1
home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$ 

home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$ ls /usr/local/lib
blas_LINUX.a    libcblaswr.a  python2.7  site_ruby
lapack_LINUX.a  node_modules  python3.4  tmglib_LINUX.a
home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$ 

home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$ ls /usr/local/include
blaswrap.h  clapack.h  f2c.h
home@home:~/projects/elsd_1.0$
```

Comment: You can add `-Wl,--verbose` to see what is the linker doing? Maybe it can provide more clue on what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks SSC, that worked, I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mail problem as solved by SSC by telling me to add -Wl --verbose to see what the linker was doing, my main problem was CLAPACK.

1. Download clapack.tgz which extracts to directory CLAPACK-3.2.1, go to this directory.
2. mv make.inc.example make.inc
3. Type make
4. Now I have blas_LINUX.a  lapack_LINUX.a  tmglib_LINUX.a in this directory.
5. Copy the header files from INCLUDE to /usr/local/include, have to chmod a+r .... to give read access
6. In elsd_1.0 edit the makefile and change "-llapack_LINUX -lblas_LINUX" to "-llapack -lblas"

I guess I did something with the .a files in step 4 maybe I moved the to /usr/local/lib.

Anyway, as long as CLAPACK can link then it works.